# how to change red5 server video file owner to apache user

Tags: java, php, red5

I have a red5 server installed. It is working fine. I want to changes the default owner of the video file created by red5 server. Currently it is root.I want this to be changed to apache so that I can delete this file through php unlink command.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bigbluebutton project does something similar wherein they run red5 as its own user, you could modify this information to use the apache user instead after installing red5.

```
  chown -R root.root /usr/share/red5
  chown -R apache:apache /usr/share/red5/log
  chmod 755 /usr/share/red5/log
  chgrp apache /usr/share/red5/webapps
  chmod 775 /usr/share/red5/webapps
```

You need to adjust the paths, groups, and users to fit your installation. I am assuming that your user and group are named "apache". The final part of this is to make sure you start red5 as the "apache" user; this will most likely require a change to your startup scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your server and it is linux, the command to change this is

```
chown name-of-new-owner:group-to-belong name-of-the-file
```

If you want to apply in many files inside a folder try -R after chown. You may need also a sudo in front of the chown.

Btw apache user and group is www-data.

Comment: I need to change the files that genreated by the red5 server means not the files that have already been generated. I want to make changes in red5 server itself so by default all the video that it generates, should have the apache as group.